# How to get bounding box coordinates in a yolo-nas model

Tags: label, coordinates, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box

I trained my custom yolo-nas model and tried to test t on my image ,it gives me the output image with bounding box and labels but how do I extract the coordinates and labels?

```
import super_gradients.training as sgt

best_model = sgt.models.get('yolo_nas_s', num_classes=1, checkpoint_path="C:/Users/Ritesh/Downloads/ckpt_best.pth")

img = "cube.jpeg"
prediction = best_model.predict(img)
```

I tried a solution from stackoverflow itself but it didn't worked

```
prediction_objects = list(prediction._images_prediction_lst)[0]
bboxes = prediction_objects.prediction.bboxes_xyxy
int_labels = prediction_objects.prediction.labels.astype(int)
class_names = prediction_objects.class_names
pred_classes = [class_names[i] for i in int_labels]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer:

```
model = models.get('yolo_nas_s',checkpoint_path='PathToModel', num_classes=Number-Of-Classes)

prediction = model.predict('Path-To-image.png', conf=0.6, fuse_model=False).show()
prediction_objects = list(prediction._images_prediction_lst)[0]

boxes = prediction_objects.prediction.bboxes_xyxy

for box in boxes:

    x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = box
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.